# When do we use Jacobian matrix or some other tests for stability of linear systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, jacobian, stability-theory

I am studying linear systems of differential equations and I am very new to the subject. Now, given a linear system $\dot{x}=Ax$ for some matrix $A$ with real entries, when we want to find stability of the origin - the equilibrium point- we may use

1. The test that uses $\det{A}=\delta$ and $Tr(A)=\tau$ so that we check the conditions on the sign of $\delta,\tau$ or $\tau^2-4\delta$
2. We first find the equilibrium points of the system and then evaluate them using the Jacobian matrix $Df(x)$. Then, depending on the signs of the real part of the eigenvalues of $Df(x^*)$, we say that for example the equilibrium point $x^*$ is a saddle.

However, I am not sure about when to use the first one or the second one. Can someone clarify the uses for  these tests?

Comment: The first test that you describe is specific to the case that $A$ has size $2 \times 2$

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to say for 2. In particular, what is the difference between "finding" equilibrium points and "evaluating" them?

Comment: @BenGrossmann, then what is the difference for the case that $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix? I edited the question.

Comment: For the second problem, it seems like you mean to say that you are evaluating **the Jacobian at the equilibrium points** rather than "evaluating the equilibrium points using the Jacobian"

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both tests are meant to be applied to a differential equation of the form
$$
\dot {\mathbf x} = f(\mathbf x),
$$
where $\mathbf x(t) \in \Bbb R^n$ for all $t \in \Bbb R$. The second test can be applied to any differential equation of this form as long as the function $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ is differentiable. The first test applies only to the specific case that $n = 2$ (so that $\mathbf x(t) = (x_1(t),x_2(t))$) and
$$
f(\mathbf x) = A \mathbf x
$$
for some ($2 \times 2$) matrix $A$.

If your problem is of the form $\dot {\mathbf x} = A \mathbf x$ and $A$ has size $2 \times 2$, then apply method 1 (since it is easier). In all other cases, method 1 does not work but method 2 does.

Comment: Thank you! I would appreciate if you could answer that "hyperbolic eq. point and degenerate eq. point" mean the same or not. It would be great if you could give me a reference book too because I checked some books including Perko's book but they rarely define anything in a precise way.

Comment: @Ninja those things are not the same. A hyperbolic equilibrium point is an eq point of a 2 dimensional system for which $Df$ has eigenvalues of opposite sign. A degenerate eq point is where one of the eigenvalues are zero.

Comment: @Ninja As for a reference, I don't have one to recommend. I suggest that you make a new post about that. Be sure to make it clear that you're looking for a reference that explains the classification of the equilibria of a *non-linear* system of (ordinary) differential equations